# Create x-axis labels using angular NVD3

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js, angularjs-nvd3-directives, angular-nvd3

I would like to create strings such as "Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday" etc for my x-axis in my nvd3 line chart below. How would I make the x-axis have a string/label instead of being numeric, in the below code:

```
$scope.options2 = {
    chart: {
        type: 'lineChart',
        height: 250,
        margin : {
            top: 20,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 40,
            left: 35
        },
        x: function(d){ return d.x; },
        y: function(d){ return d.y; },
        useInteractiveGuideline: true,
        dispatch: {
            stateChange: function(e){ console.log("stateChange"); },
            changeState: function(e){ console.log("changeState"); },
            tooltipShow: function(e){ console.log("tooltipShow"); },
            tooltipHide: function(e){ console.log("tooltipHide"); }
        },
        xAxis: {
            axisLabel: 'Time'
        },
        yAxis: {
            axisLabel: 'cd(ng/ml)',
            tickFormat: function(d){
                return d3.format('.02f')(d);
            },
            axisLabelDistance: -10
        },
        callback: function(chart){
            console.log("!!! lineChart callback !!!");
        }
    },
    title: {
        enable: true,
        text: 'Afternoon'
    },
    subtitle: {
        enable: false,
        text: '',
        css: {
            'text-align': 'center',
            'margin': '10px 13px 0px 7px'
        }
    }
};

var datax = [{
    "key" : "cope",
    "values" : [{"y" : 5,"x" : 2,},{"y" : 4,"x" : 1,}, {"y" : 4,"x" : 0,}]
}];    
$scope.data2 = datax;
```

I am using this library: https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: wrote post thinking you wanted the month, so changed to weekday...

What you're looking for is the `xAxis.tickFormat` method. Assuming you're using moment.js in your app, you could simply do the following:

```
xAxis: {
  axisLabel: 'Time',
  tickFormat: function(d) {
    return moment().weekday(d).format('dddd');; // for 0, returns 'Sunday'
                                             // 'Sun' if format 'ddd'
  }
}
```

If you're not using moment, then you can just create a weekdays array and map the x-value to the same index in the array:

```
var daysOfWeek = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
...
tickFormat: function(d) {
    return daysOfWeek[d];
},...
```

[Here's a plunker with the moment.js example implemented](http://plnkr.co/edit/WZ52c9oBmnImMscESriD?p=preview). Hope this helps!